# Javascript count up asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, timer

I have been trying to find this solution online, but no luck so far. I need a simple JavaScript code (HH:MM:SS) that count seconds up. I have an asp.net c# web application. I want to run that count on the page load. What JavaScript should be capable of doing is:
When it reaches 2 min, change the background of the timer to yellow.
When it reaches 4 min, change the background of the timer to red.
When it reaches 10 min, play .mp3 or wav file.

Can anybody point to right direction?
It doesn't necessarily have to be done in JavaScript. If I can do it in c# asp.net that's fine with me.

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: there is a really good site for learning `JavaScript` [Learn Java Script](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) I would suggest starting there

Comment: I'd suggest not using that site! http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter:

```
 var count = 0;
 count ++;
```

Timer:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(everySecond, 1000);

function everySecond()
{  // do something
}
```

Check if counter is above 120 seconds or 240 seconds:

```
if (count > 120)
{ ....
}
```

Setting color: have 2 CSS styles based on class and swithc class when needed... I.e. [JQuery.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) - `$("#myText").addClass("myRedBackground");`